# Access function through base class pointer in multilevel inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, multi-level

below is the multilevel inheritance hierarchy

```
class A
{
public:
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Hello from A"<<endl;
  }

};

class B:public A
{
  public:
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Hello from B"<<endl;
  }
};

class C:public B
{
  public:
  void print()
  {
    cout<<"Hello from C"<<endl;
  }
} 

int main()
{
 A *Child = new C;
 //Need to call class B function using Child pointer;

}
```

How to do that?? I know by static_cast but not able to achieve correct syntax...since i am new to casting.

Comment: `static_cast<B*>(Child)->print();`.

Comment: My first idea was: This is for what `virtual` was invented. But, making `print()` `virtual` would mean: `A->print();` calls actually `C::print()`. (`C::print()` might call `B::print()` internally. I use this often e.g. when overriding event handlers of widgets where handling of base class shall be enhanced by handling of derived class.) What you want to achieve can be done as mentioned by @songyuanyao but I would consider this as bad design (and look for a better one).

Comment: @Scheff do you think multi level inheritance help in real life scenarios ? can you comment

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks for your help

Comment: IMHO, "multi level inheritance" is very common. You may have a look into Qt. doc (concerning the widget classes) e.g. [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) <- [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) <- [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html) <- [`QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html). ("<-" ... inherits) My own class libraries are often similar regarding this. (I'm addicted to build class trees...) ;-)